# Connect Cortana to Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cortana

I would like to know, if it is possible to connect Cortana to Chrome in some way.

Basically, I want to execute some javascript functions on a webpage when I tell it to Cortana. 
Example: Hey Cortana, volume up. In this case I would have a js function which would be executed.

I have some clue, how to tell Cortana what to do, but I have no idea if I can connect it to the browser in any way.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**
Maybe I was not clear enough.

I am looking for a `framework` that can `connect to an already opened browser`, and execute javascript commands in it. If possible `using .net` because I want Cortana to execute it.

Comment: Perhaps you should [consult the Cortana documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I could not find any option to connect Cortana directly to Chrome, so I ended up adding a middleware(nodeJS server). An absolutely undocumented, with full of default names, version I added to [github](https://github.com/kisnandor2/Cortana_NodeJS_Youtube), maybe someone can use it as a starting point.